# Visual studio не работает exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

На днях закончил небольшой проект на windows forms (C++) и решил все проверить. Нажал на кнопку build project. Проект скомпилировался и получился exe файл. На моем win 10 x64 все работает но вот если запустить проект на win 7 или в принципе на другом ПК. Видает ошибку што ему не хватает какого то dll.
[image: .dll missing]
Что деать так как решений не нашел.

Comment: Подозреваю, вам нужен vcredist под вашу версию студии.

Comment: Чтобы скопировать текст в диалоговом окне, просто нажмите Ctrl+C, когда оно в фокусе - текст скопируется в буфер обмена. После чего вставьте его куда надо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, круто, не знал о такой возможности.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, ему не хватает [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) - всех необходимых для работы библиотек.

Но можно скомпоновать файл со статической линковкой всех библиотек - тогда он будет побольше, но зато будет работать даже там, где нет библиотек Visual Studio.

Comment: Да но как ето зделать?

Comment: Дополнение - для распространяемых приложений, желательно проводить Release сборку (судя по фотографии автор собирает в Debug, и Redistributable здесь не спасет).

Comment: Что именно? Первый вариант - установить на машине этот самый Redistributable - он распространяется бесплатно. Второй - указать в настройках проекта (опциях компилятора) компоновать библиотеки статически. Да, есть еще одна хитрость - указание минимальной версии Windows, где может работать программа (в опциях линковщика), но это не ваш вариант, там бы вообще не запуситилось...